# How to get child-index of html element using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parent-child

I am trying to get the index of child of its parent.
For example:-

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tr id="rahul">
            <td> Hi this is ABC </td>
            <td> Hi this is XYZ </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

And my java script code is:-

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        document.onmousedown = mouseDown;
        function mouseDown(e) {
            var element =  document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX,e.clientY);
            console.log("Clicked element is:" + element.tagName);
            var i=1;
            while (element.nextSibling != null) {
                element = element.nextSibling;
                console.log('Sibling No:' + (i++) + " " + element.tagName);
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

When i click on "Hi this is ABC" according to me, it should print

```
Sibling No.1 TD
```

But actually It is printing

```
Clicked element is:TD jsoupTest.html:10
Sibling No:1 undefined jsoupTest.html:14
Sibling No:2 TD jsoupTest.html:14
Sibling No:3 undefined
```

It arises a doubt why this is printing undefined as sibling of TD?
And my idea is to find the no of siblings clicked element has and i can find out the total no of children its parent has. So now I can find the index of clicked element by subtracting no of siblings from total children of its parent.

Please tell me if there is any better alternative to get this.

Comment: As you're using jQuery (I'm inferring this from `$(document).ready(...)`), I've added the jQuery tag to your question -- as it will affect the answers pretty markedly. (E.g.: This is one line with jQuery, multiple lines without.)

Comment: You are getting `undefined` because between the `td` element nodes (and after the last one), there is a text node (containing the white space characters) and text nodes don't have a tag name. Use `element.nodeName` instead and you will see.

Comment: Since indices are normally given zero-based in javascript, you might be better to start with `var i = 0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know what index a child **element** is relative to its sibling **elements**, jQuery can do that for you via [`index`](http://api.jquery.com/index) (see further down if you want to consider non-element nodes):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.onmousedown = mouseDown;
    function mouseDown(e) {
        var element =  document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX,e.clientY);
        console.log("Clicked element is:" + element.tagName);
        console.log("Index: " + $(element).index());
    }
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ojimoj) | [source](http://jsbin.com/ojimoj/edit)

Note that that only considered **elements**, and not other kinds of nodes (in particular, [text nodes](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-1312295772)) that may be there. This is what you want probably about 90% of the time, possibly more. :-) If you really want to consider other node types, not just elements, use `$.inArray(element, $(element).parent().contents())` rather than `$(element).index()`, e.g.:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.onmousedown = mouseDown;
    function mouseDown(e) {
        var element =  document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX,e.clientY);
        console.log("Clicked element is:" + element.tagName);
        console.log("Index: " + $.inArray(element, $(element).parent().contents()));
        // ^--- this is the only line that changed
    }
});
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/ojimoj/2) | [source](http://jsbin.com/ojimoj/2/edit)

---

Side note: I'm fairly sure you can replace your line

```
var element =  document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX,e.clientY);
```

...with

```
var element =  e.target;
```

...as `target` will be the topmost element under the mouse when the button was pressed.

Comment: `$(element).index()` suffices.

Comment: @FelixKling You should put that in its own answer.

Comment: Thanks T.J. Crowder once again for your super awesome answer :):)

Answer (score 1):

First, you should use the `click` event instead of `mousedown`. Then, you should not use a `on<event>`-property but a proper way to add a listener, jQuery (which you already have loaded) offers a simple and cross-browser way.

Next, don't use `document.elementFromPoint` with the coordinates of the mouse event - just use the `target` property of the event.

```
$(document).on("click", function(e) {
     var element = e.target;
     ...
});
```

Then, your loop:

```
        var i=1;
        while (element.nextSibling != null) {
            element = element.nextSibling;
            console.log('Sibling No:' + (i++) + " " + element.tagName);
        }
```

This code prints all siblings that come after the `element`. This does not seem to be what you want. You want to count the siblings before it, right? Use `.previousSibling` then.

Also, it includes text nodes, logging `undefined` for their `nodeName`. To get around that, you can use `[previous|next]ElementSibling`.

> ...find out the total no of children its parent has

Oh, thats a much easier task:

```
element.parentNode.children.length;
// or even
element.parentNode.childElementCount;
// to include text nodes:
element.parentNode.childNodes.length;
```

Comment: I just came across this now and found out your answer was really cool..Surprised why I didn't upvote earlier..Thanks :)